# Vercel Production Branch is stripping Authorization header on POST to Serverless Function API

Tags: next.js, serverless, vercel, authorization-header

Nothing special about the API but I have a serverless function POST API which expects an Authorization header to validate and then writes to a db.

For example:

```sh
     curl --location --request POST 'https://myserver.server.com/api/endpoint' \
        --header 'Authorization: Bearer blahblahblahblah'
```

In a Vercel Preview branch I'm able to get this to work and the `Authorization` header is passed to my API as expected.  When I test this out in production the `Authorization` header is stripped from the request (figured that out by logging the raw request headers).  What's are the difference between Preview and Production with respect to `Authorization` headers?  What do I need to do to forward the header in Production?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same here - not sure what to do with that one :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Vercel (Support is already notified) so let's wait for what they say. I'm assuming they consume the `authorization` header themselves and drop it afterward. It's a bit strange that this only happens in **PROD** but we shall see.

### Workaround

Luckily, for us, this is quite easy to workaround. I've posted my updated function to illustrate the point. The main thing is to use **any** header other than **authorization**

I'm using `x_authorization`, but the name is entirely arbitrary.

```js
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    //using 'custom' x_authorization header because the regular 'authorization' header is stripped by Vercel in PROD environments.
    const { x_authorization } = req.headers

    if (x_authorization === `Bearer ${process.env.CRON_API_KEY}`) {
      
      //TODO: YOU DO YOUR THING HERE!!!

      res.status(200).json()
    } else {
      res.status(401).end()
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST')
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet.  I've also used a similar workaround but instead of custom header I'm passing the authorization in the POST body.  My code will actually check the normal header and fall back to the body if authorization is missing from the header.

Comment: @caseinc care to mark the response as answer?

Answer (score 3):

I just had this issue and think I found the reason it was only affecting production for you and more or less the root cause. It seems to have to do with vercel's forwarding rules.

When I sent the request to mydomain.com the authentication header was stripped but when I sent to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) the header remained there. This makes sense because I have the "recommended" forwarding rules from vercel that forwards mydomain.com to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)

Comment: That's a right answer